# Ubuntu 15.10 doesnt let me open an NTFS drive

Tags: dual-boot, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

Hey can someone help me? I'm sorry if this question was asked before but I'm trying to open a 640GB Volume from the Launcher and I get this error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/ubuntu/98C83D3AC83D1848: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb2" "/media/ubuntu/98C83D3AC83D1848"' exited with non-zero exit status 12: Failed to read last sector (1250256894): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I'm really new to this, today is my first day trying Ubuntu as the primary OS on my PC (secondary would be Windows 7) and I'd like to know how to access this drive if possible. It's not the drive with the Windows 7 OS.

Comment: you may want to run a drive diagnostic tool. My favorite hard drive diagnostic tool is ViVARD you can find it on UBCD

Comment: The volume is corrupt: it claims that it is larger than the partition it is in.  You will need to reformat it.

Comment: Reformatting it isnt an option, given that more than half of it is full.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

[Visit this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2102917) and you'll find the solution to your problems as it has already happened to others. You drive has an SFS Dynamic Partitioning Scheme which is proprietary and owned by Microsoft. Check the comment made by user "Oldfred" in the link, it will come in handy! Cheers!

**ORIGINAL**

I think that the partition may be corrupt given the message that it shows but don't give up just yet. Ubuntu is a great GNU/Linux operating system, it's a shame that you have this kind of trouble.

I had a similar problem, have you tried using `ntfs-3g` or `ntfsfix`? or `mount` with `ntfs-3g` options? Was the NTFS drive in hibernation? Did it suffer a power cut?

Part of the `man` page of `ntfsfix` reads as follows:

```
ntfsfix is a utility that fixes some common NTFS problems.
ntfsfix is NOT a Linux version of chkdsk. It only repairs some
fundamental NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal file and
schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows.

You may run ntfsfix on an NTFS volume if you think it was damaged by
Windows or some other way and it cannot be mounted.
```

Try this:

`ntfsfix /path/to/ntfsdevice`

In your case it would be:

`ntfsfix /dev/sda2`

Where `/dev/sda2` is the NTFS partition with the issue. `ntfsfix` has some useful options like:

`ntfsfix -b /dev/sda2`

The `-b` options does the following: `Clear the list of bad sectors. This is useful after cloning an old disk with bad sectors to a new disk.`

Or:

`ntfsfix -d /dev/sda2`

The `-d` option does the following:

```
Clear the volume dirty flag if the volume can be fixed and mounted.
If the option is not present or the volume cannot be  fixed the dirty
volume flag is set to request a volume checking at next mount.
```

Hope this helps. Don't hesitate to ask again. Cheers!

Comment: Okay, well i tried the ntfsfix /dev/sda2 and i get
'ubuntu@ubuntu-Inspiron-560:~$ ntfsfix /dev/sda2
Refusing to operate on read-write mounted device /dev/sda2.'

Comment: Sorry, did you use elevated privileges,`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2`?

Comment: i did try that aswell, it gave me the same thing.

Comment: can you give me the output of  `sudo fsck /dev/sda2`, thanks

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu-Inspiron-560:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sda2
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2

Comment: Sorry, I can only see the version of the program `2.26.2`, is that all the output that the command gives you? nothing more?

Comment: Yes, thats all it says.

Comment: Then, my friend, I'm afraid the Partition or the drive must have another kind of problem. You could use `testdisk` to recover the NTFS partition. There are many tutorials that show you how to use this tool. Be VERY CAREFUL when following the instructions. Sorry.

Comment: could it be because that partition is a dynamic partiton and not a basic one?

Comment: Important piece of information; AFAIK, Dynamic Partitions/Disks are a Microsoft-only technology but there are several workarounds to get them mounted and working in GNU/Linux operating systems. The catch is that it's not easy to do so.

Comment: although it is possible? if so can i get some tutorials or tips?

Comment: Of course! One last thing though, could you give the output of `sudo fdisk -l` for future references, one of the "tutorials" would be this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/548842/weird-ntfs-partition-display

Comment: fdisk: invalid option -- '1'

Comment: thats the short version, the rest was just Usage:
 fdisk [options] <disk>      change partition table
 fdisk [options] -l [<disk>] list partition table(s)

Display or manipulate a disk partition table.
 followed by Options

Comment: Also that link pretty much tells me to format that drive, and its not really an option right now... although i might buy another HDD and transfer the data from this dynamic one to the new one to format the dynamic one.

Comment: Hello, be careful when using the commands given here by the community, in my last comment the option was not the number '1' , it was a lowercase 'L' like this `l`. It's better to copy and paste the commands in your terminal window rather than writing them manually. Please give the ouput of this command `sudo fdisk -l` remember to copy/paste

Comment: Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type


Disk /dev/sdb: 596,2 GiB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc9498eaf

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1          63 1250261679 1250261617 596,2G 42 SFS

Comment: I tried keeping what i thought was needed there, cause all the output was too much for this comment section.

Comment: Hello there, did you finally solve it?